# JSON response with multiline from rails is not parsed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a simple application in rails, its supposed to respond to json with this show.js.erb,

```
 { "opening": "<%= @frame.opening %>", "closing": "<%= @frame.closing %>"}
```

The issue is that when @frame.opening is multi-line then in jquery will not parse this as an object(instead it will be a string),

the error is

> "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token

note that if I use \n in the text that is @frame.opening there will be no problem, only if I use the the enter key in the string will it break.
Let me know if there is any need for more information.

Comment: It should be `show.json.erb`, not `show.js.erb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't encode JSON by hand! It's hard to do (as you're noticing), and plus, it's much simpler to let Rails do it for you. Try this:

```
{ opening: @frame.opening, closing: @frame.closing }.to_json
```

`to_json` will spit out a properly-formed JSON string for you to use, handling newlines and more. For example:

```
pry(main)> hash = { foo: "asdfasdf
pry(main)*
pry(main)* asdfsf" }
pry(main)> puts hash.to_json
{"foo":"asdfasdf\n\nasdfsf"}
```

OP edit: Since I assume more people will be encountering this, I had to add .html_safe since the ERB was adding stuff to make it work for HTML, but its a JSON.

I should not use a view for this, but in any case, it should look like this,

```
 <%= {}.to_json.html_safe %>
```